# ios detect connected Network name in simulator and device

Tags: ios

Iam trying to get the network name to which the iOS simulator is connected using this code

```
-(void)getNetworkName
{
 CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
    NSDictionary *dict = ( NSDictionary*) myDict;
    NSString* ssid = [dict objectForKey:@"SSID"];

    NSString * netWorkName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ssid];

    NSLog(@"%@",netWorkName);

}
```

it works fine for device but when run on iOS simulator

```
 CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
```

throws exc_bad_acess please help me to get the network name in simulator.

Comment: This does not work in the simulator. You have to run it in a device.

Comment: @Thedude ya I got that but how to get in simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNCopySupportedInterfaces() returns nil in the simulator. You are trying to access the first element of the array in `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0)`, and that causes the app to crash.

Try the following code. It only accesses the array in case it has some element.

```
- (NSString *)getNetworkName {
    // Does not work on the simulator.
    NSString *ssid = nil;
    NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
        NSDictionary *info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam);
        if (info[@"SSID"]) {
            ssid = info[@"SSID"];
        }
    }
    return ssid;
}
```

Comment: is there any way we can get the network connectes in iOS Simulator ?

Comment: @user3115014 Not that I know, sorry.